# Extract all links (including multiple links per line) in markdown file

Tags: bash, sed, gnu, pattern-matching, markdown

### Sample markdown file:

```
cat index.md

# Abstract

- To achieve [Work Life Balance](./WorkLifeBalance/WorkLifeBalance.md), first understand what it means and what are the requirements.
- Develop right **[Attitude](./Attitude/index.md)** and [Haha](./Haha/Haha.md).
- Understand **[attention](./AttentionManagement/index.md)**, **[time](./TimeManagement/index.md)** and **[task](./TaskManagement/index.md)** management and start implementing those.
```

### Expected outcome

```markdown
[Work Life Balance](./WorkLifeBalance/WorkLifeBalance.md)
[Attitude](./Attitude/index.md)
[Haha](./Haha/Haha.md)
[attention](./AttentionManagement/index.md)
[time](./TimeManagement/index.md)
[task](./TaskManagement/index.md)
```

## Attempts to solve

`sed -r -n -e 's/.*(\[.*\]\(.*\)).*/\1/p' index.md`, but this only mnatches the last link in a line!

## Suggestions?

I prefer sed, but if its not possible in sed then other tools are also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround:

```
sed -r -e 's/\[/\n[/g' index.md  | sed -r -e 's/.*(\[.*\]\(.*\)).*/\n\1/g' | grep -oE '\[.*\]\(.*\)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -En '/\[/{s/[^[]*(\[[^)]*\))[^[]*/\1/g;/\[[^[]*\[/s/\[[^)]*\)/\n&/2g;p}' input_file
[Work Life Balance](./WorkLifeBalance/WorkLifeBalance.md)
[Attitude](./Attitude/index.md)
[Haha](./Haha/Haha.md)
[attention](./AttentionManagement/index.md)
[time](./TimeManagement/index.md)
[task](./TaskManagement/index.md)
```